# How can I prevent "cargo doc" from exporting pub(crate) items

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

I am trying to generate rustdoc for only my public facing API.  I would like this to include `pub` but not `pub(crate)` items.

Is there a way to indicate this without having to exclude each item individually?

```rust
pub struct DocumentMe;

// I do not want to have to
// explicitly specify excluding this
#[doc(hidden)]
pub(crate) struct DoNotDocumentMe;
```

As @Chayim Friedman posted in the comments, this is only an issue with binary crates, and not library crates.

Comment: `cargo doc` does not do this by default. Perhaps it's a binary and not a library crate?

Comment: From the book "Rustdoc is supposed to include everything users need to use the crate fully and nothing more.".  If pub(crate) is not exposed as public API, why is it included by default?

Comment: And from the next paragraph in the book, "pub(crate) is another great tool for removing implementation details from the public API. It allows items to be used from outside of their own module but not outside of the same crate."

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes its a binary.  Switching to library removed those items.  With that said, why should it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Rust 1.41, private APIs in binary crates are documented by default. Since the API is not exported to anyone (as this is a binary), Rust assumes that you want to document the API for consumers of the source code, so it also documents private items.

In library crates, you can change the default and also document private items using the `--document-private-items` flag. Sadly, I don't think there is an option to not document private items for binary crates. [In the PR that changed the default for Rust 1.41, it was said that the PR can go without a flag to change the default and that such flag can be added in the future if there is a demand for it](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/7593#issuecomment-557152039). I don't think this ever happened.